# Can someone explain the difference of mean and linear bias in residual analysis?

Tags: regression, mean, residuals, bias

I am struggling in understand the difference between mean and linear biased.

What does it mean the a regression has mean biased or linear biased? How do I interpret it?

Comment: can you provide the formal definitions of those two concepts?

Comment: When comparing predicted vs observed in residual regression mean biased i significant if the intercept of this regression is different from 0. LInear biased is significant if the slope f this regression is different from 0.
I would like to have a simple explanation and interpretation on these terms...as I already know how to calculate them...